# Save a webpage or nokogiri doc to a database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, ubuntu

I did a bit of searching but came up empty on this. I'm looking to store a webpage to a database field so that the source code can be reviewed later on (I don't want to save to a file because I'm on Heroku).

I've tried: 
`Model.create(:text => open(url)` and
`Model.create(:text => Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)))`

However, neither of these seem to save the page source code. I assume that I'm missing a step here, but could someone steer me in the right direction?

**Edit #1**
When I tried to_s on my Nokogiri::HTML document, I'm getting an empty string. This is my code below. The reason for the long user-agent is that Google shows different results depending on the user agent and I'm trying to mimic a desktop user agent.
`Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=apple", 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2'), nil, 'utf-8').to_s`

**Edit #2**
Very strange. This code returns an empty string as well. I checked with some other people and they were not getting empty strings.
`text = open("http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=apple", 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2').read`

**Edit #3**
I found that there must be something wrong with my ruby installation on Windows 7. I tried on an ubuntu installation I'm running as a guest on my windows machine and it worked as expected. Gonna code on the ubuntu installation from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call the `#to_s` method of the `Document` class in Nokogiri. You can do it like this:

```
text = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://google.com")).to_s
MyModel.create(:text => text)
```

Make sure the `text` column in your Model is of the type `text`.

Edit: Since you don't need Nokogiri for anything, you can just use `open-uri`:

```
require 'open-uri'
text = open("http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=apple", 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2').read
MyModel.create(:text => text)
```

Comment: Thanks. Still seem to be having some trouble I think possibly because of how my document is formatted. Please see my edit above.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble with Nokogiri. Is there a way to just save the webpage source code without using Nokogiri?

Comment: Running your code above I get what seems to be a positive reply: https://raw.github.com/gist/1503946/0c0bd7df76c893b1f0e7c343eba159f86eda7794/foo

Comment: I updated the answer so you can see how to do it without Nokogiri.

Comment: It must be my ruby or ruby gems that are acting weird, since I just tried on a different machine and it worked fine.